# Rearrange $x^3 -3x + 3 = \sin(x)$

Tags: calculus

I have $x^3 -3x +3 = \sin(x)$ and have been asked to show it has a solution in the interval $[-3,-2].$ 
I'm fine with doing this, but I feel like I need the equation in a $y=\dots$ form. 
I tried rearranging and got $y=(\sin(x)/(x^3 -3x +3)) -1,$
but I definitely feel this is wrong. 
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Try subtraction instead: 
$$
y(x)  = x^3 - 3x + 3 - sin(x)
$$

You now want to show that there's a value $x$ with $-3 \le x\le 2$ such that $y(x) = 0$.

Comment: Do I do this by evaluating the derivative at x=-3 and x=-2 and if there is a change of sign then there is a guaranteed solution in that interval?

Comment: I suggest you look for a theorem that shows that a function has a zero in an interval. The one you suggest is no use (indeed, it's not a theorem). Look at $y = x^2 + 1$; its derivatives at $-3$ and $2$ have opposite signs, but it's not zero anywhere on that interval.

Comment: Ah thankyou. I was thinking of the Intermediate Value Theorem but didnt realise it was just the function evaluated at the points.

Comment: Extension: how would I then show that there are no real solutions with x outside of the interval [-3,-2]??

Comment: 1. That's a separate question, which you should ask separately. 2. Draw a graph.